# jquery prevObject вместо выбираемого объекта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем добрый день!
Застопорился на мелочи:

```js
function a(id){
    var something = $('div#some_'+id);
    console.log(something);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="someid1" onclick="a(this.id)">click</a>
    <div id="some_someid1"> ... </div>
    <a href="#" id="someid2" onclick="a(this.id)">click</a>
    <div id="some_someid2"> ... </div>
    <a href="#" id="someid3" onclick="a(this.id)">click</a>
    <div id="some_someid3"> ... </div>
```

В консоль возвращает:

```
[prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "div#some_someid1"]
```

очень бы хотелось, что бы все возвращало нужный `div` по `id`, дабы дальше с ним манипулировать. Ранее с таким не встречался - не могу понять в чем проблема.

**UPDATE**

Могут ли быть проблемой вот такие вот страшные `id`

`b22ab51f-8e8f-11dc-9cc7-0015170f33dc+b22ab533-8e8f-11dc-9cc7-0015170f33dc`

Comment: копируешь слово "some"

Comment: попробуй var something = $('div#'+id);

Comment: проблема то в чем? что вы ожидаете увидеть в консоли? Подобные длинные идентификаторы (GUID+GUID) сами по себе проблемы никаой не сделают, ибо содержат допустимые символы, если рассматривать html5, в старом html4 символ `+` не является допустимым при указании id

Comment: @user202854  дак и в атрибутах указано `some_someid1`.

Comment: @teran, я очень желаю увидеть объект `div#some_someid1`, дабы дальше получить его детишек, взять из них значения и отправить `ajax`-ом по своим делам...

Comment: я оформил ваш код в виде сниппета, не вижу проблемы. `prevObject` это одно из свойств объекта, если браузер вдруг рисует его вначале, то это ничего не значит. Чтобы проверить, нашелся ли объект по селектору - проверьте значение `length`

Comment: ты ж jquery используешь. тогда делай по культурнее: $(window).load(function(){ $("a[id^=someid]").click(function(){ console.log($("div#"+$(this).prop("id"))) }) })

Comment: @teran в живом коде выдает `length = 0`

Comment: все, проблема все же была в плюсе, заменил на `_` все заработало. эх, надо сервер обновлять, да нельзя(

Comment: а jquery рассматривал данный плюс, как селектор. чтобы испоьзовать его как id, пришлось бы тогда писать `$("div[id=" + id + '"])` писать, видимо. Так что да, селектор валидный с точки зрения html, но косячный с точки зрения jquery, т.к. + имеет свое значение в css.